# using ksh shebang in a bash script

Tags: bash

We will perform a migration from unix to Linux.
the typeset -L only works with ksh

I created the following file:

```
#!/bin/ksh -u

echo $SHELL
typeset -L21 RUN_LOGL="LOG_FILE    "
```

Normally the shebang should indicate the correct interpreter (ksh). But when I call the script in a bash way:

```
$ . test.ksh
```

The output is:

```
/bin/bash

-bash: typeset: -L: invalid option

typeset: usage: typeset [-aAfFilrtux] [-p] name[=value] ...
```

the script is interpreter in bash way , and typeset -L is not accepted.
whereas if I simply call

```
$test.ksh
```

it runs fine.

Is the way we call the script (bash way or ksh way) important enough to ignore the shebang ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9):

```
. test.ksh
```

Does *not* execute the script. It is [*sourcing*](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html) the script.

Sourcing a script *always* ignores the shebang. The shebang is only used when the script is *executed* like:

```
chmod +x test.ksh
./test.ksh
```

Comment: If I call test.ksh without "." or "./" from inside another script , am I running the shebang #!/bin/ksh -u ?

Comment: You're executing the script, yes.

Comment: @Topas `. file.sh` and `./file.sh` are **entirely** different things. The former (`. file.sh`) is sourcing the file in the current shell. `./file.sh` is *running* the file as a script/binary on its own (and uses the shebang of the script).

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I possible print the information of which interpreter I'm currently using ? I guess is not echo $SHELL , because this print me bash instead of ksh as specified by #!/bin/ksh -u (I'm running in a bash shell)

Comment: If you're currently running in a bash shell then your current interpreter is bash.

Answer (score 0):

The shebang is only used if the interpreter was not defined previously, e.g.:

```
sh myScript.sh
```

will always invoke your `sh`, and ignores the shebang.